# How to debug dotnet core spa with angular 6

Tags: angular, debugging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

After I upgraded my angular app to angular 6 with "@angular/cli": "^6.2.3" my typescript breakpoints do not work anymore. I am using VS Code as an IDE and chrome debugger extension.

my launch.json looks like this

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"compounds": [{
    "name": "Core & Chrome",
    "configurations": [
        "Chrome",
        ".NET Core"
    ]
}],
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:5000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/pp-images.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
        "externalConsole": true,
        "launchBrowser": {
            "enabled": false,
            "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cmd.exe",
                "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
            },
            "osx": {
                "command": "open"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "xdg-open"
            }
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Everything worked correctly when I was using "@angular/cli": "1.6.8" with angular 5 so I am a bit stumped now and don't really want to downgrade it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

.scripts in the debugger windows doesn't return any information.

### **UPDATE**

I figured it out finally. Had to change "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/wwwroot" to "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/ClientApp" and it worked! Hope this helps someone.